# How to plot 2D data points with color according to third column value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose I have an array with three columns:

```
>>>print(arr)
array(
    [[1 2 -1]
    [1 3 1]
    [3 2 -1]
    [5 2 -1]]
)
```

Suppose I want to turn this into a scatter plot:

```
plt.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,1], 'xr')
```

Works fine. But, all the scattered points look like a **red 'x'**. Suppose I want to have a red 'x' if the third column value is -1, and a **blue 'o'** if the value is 1. How do I do that?

Is this possible to achieve with `plt.plot()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the color *and*  the marker, you need to plot several scatter plots, at least one for each marker.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, -1],
              [1, 3, 1],
              [3, 2, -1],
              [5, 2, -1]])
mapping= {-1: ("red", "x"), 1: ("blue", "o")}

for c in np.unique(a[:,2]):
    d = a[a[:,2] == c]
    plt.scatter(d[:,0], d[:,1], c=mapping[c][0], marker=mapping[c][1])
    #plt.plot(d[:,0], d[:,1], color=mapping[c][0], marker=mapping[c][1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Using a `plot` is equally possible (see commented line in code).

Comment: I feel like you're always watching `matplotlib` tags. But I'm happy to learn other solutions from you.

Comment: Is it possible to plot, than change the colors?

Comment: @BlooB Yes that would be possible, but since you cannot use different markers in the same scatter plot, you may as well directly set the color as done in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your list, and consider that the 3rd item of each sublist is the color. Attribute the color according to the data you have. Here, I assign the value `'r'` to `c` if `c == -1`, else, it will be equal to `'b'`, meaning *blue*.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

arr = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 3, 1], [3, 2, -1], [5, 2, -1]]

for x, y, color in arr:
    c = 'r' if color == -1 else 'b'
    plt.plot(x, y, 'x' + c)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is for sure a valid solution, just mind that you create one plot per point. If the array in use has a lot of rows to plot, this will quickly become a performance issue.

Comment: Well, I tried [:, 0], but it didn't work. I didn't think about numpy arrays at first, but I realized it later on. Do you think calling once `plt.plot()` with an array is way faster than several times `plt.plot()` with a single value for x and y ?

Comment: Yes, each call to `plt.plot` creates one `Line2D` artist. Memory-wise it's already better to have a single object stored than a multitude of them. Speedwise it is a lot faster to draw one `Line2D` object with N nodes than drawing N `Line2D` objects with one node each. This will not be observable for a low number of points as here, I guess one would see significant difference from ~1000 points onwards.

Answer (score 0):

as a fellow Python beginner I have had a similar question recently and for me the best solution was to use the fantastic "[seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html)" package.

The trick is to combine Pandas '[DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)' and Seaborn's "[FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid)" objects and let them do all the work. Here's how I did it for your particular example:

- Import pandas and seaborn
- Convert the array into a dataframe
- Create a seaborn facetgrid together with matplotlib scatter plot
- Use the great "Hue" parameter to get the colours right

Here is my code:

## Import the necessary libraries

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
```

## Create the Pandas DataFrame

```
a = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, -1],
    [1, 3, 1],
    [3, 2, -1],
    [5, 2, -1]])

a.columns=['A','B','C']
```

## Generate the seaborn FacetGrid and use **Hue** for the colours

```
sns.FacetGrid(a, hue="C", size=2).map(plt.scatter, "A", "B").add_legend()
plt.show()
```

***Voila !***

[image: Scatterplot with Hue]

Obviously this is a trivial example, but with real data the result is great and easy to reproduce (see below)

[image]

*PS: This is my very first post on stackoverflow - it feels like the beginning of something*

Comment: The questions asks for a red x and a blue dot. Without that requirement, this would be a valid answer. Maybe you want to incorporate using different markers into this?